# Usage of const directive in C++ in general, in particular in Tiny XML Library:

Tags: c++, constants, tinyxml

I'm an experienced developer in a few compiled OOP languages, particularly Object Pascal and C#. Have 'messed around' with C++ for years but recently started getting more serious about C++ development.

Most of concepts in C++ are quite easy for me to grasp based on my experience with other languages. But one thing that I'm finding quite difficult is the ways in which the `const` directive is used and how it behaves in C++.

In particular, at the moment I'm faced with this problem, using the [TinyXML Library](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml/) in Netbeans C++ IDE, on an Ubuntu 12.04 machine and default mingW/G++ tool chain:

I'm calling this function:

```
TiXmlNode::TiXmlNode* FirstChild()
```

In the TinyXML source there are two overloaded public versions of this function in class `TiXmlNode`:

```
const TiXmlNode* FirstChild() const { return firstChild; }  

TiXmlNode* FirstChild() { return firstChild; }
```

They are identical except for the const directive. I assumed that the version called would be dependent on how I declared the variable I was loading from the function, for example:

```
const TiXmlNode* aNode = node->FirstChild();
```

Would call the const version of the function

```
TiXmlNode* aNode = node->FirstChild();
```

Would call the second version, without const.

But when I try to use the second form in my code, I get a compiler error:

> **error: invalid conversion from ‘const TiXmlNode*’ to ‘TiXmlNode*’
>   [-fpermissive]**

Why is this happening? How do I use the version of the function without const? What am I missing here?

More - where can I find a good summary of the usages of `const` directive in C++ 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, the overload chosen depends on the type of `node`, not the type of `aNode`.

`const` at the end of the member function declaration indicates that the function may be called on a const instance of the object; a member function lacking `const` there cannot be. When both `const` and non-`const` overloads are present, overload resolution prefers the `const` version when applicable.

Apparently, `node` is of type `const TiXmlNode*`, so `FirstChild() const` overload is chosen, and the return value is of type `const TiXmlNode*`. This cannot be converted to `TiXmlNode*`.

Here's a textbook example. `std::vector<T>` provides two overloads of `operator[]`, looking like this (greatly simplified):

```
template <typename T>
class vector {
  T* storage_;
public:
  T& operator[](size_t index) { return storage_[index]; }
  const T& operator[](size_t index) const { return storage_[index]; }
};
```

With this, you could write:

```
vector<int> v;
v[0] = 42;  // OK: calls int& operator[](size_t)
const vector<int> cv;
cv[0] = 42;  // Error: calls const int& operator[](size_t) const
```

As expected, `const vector` can't be modified, while non-const one can be.

Comment: "const at the end of the member function declaration" - I assume you mean the second use of const in **const TiXmlNode* FirstChild() const { return firstChild; }** . I have to digest this a bit and I should be able to accept this answer.  I am quite confused at this point about the usages of _const_ .